# If array is copy type, how accessing element and appending element works, is it internally use pointer derefencing operator as like C i.e. (*(a + 2))

Tags: ios, swift

array is copy type in swift, then how accessing element and appending element works of array, is it internally use pointer dereferencing operator as like C  i.e.  (*(a + 2))

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. First, it's a _value_ type, so it will be copied upon assignment (in a more or less optimized _copy on write_ way). Appending is no problem unless your array is a `let` constant. If you want to know how it's implemented, you should watch for the source code.

Comment: Useful resources: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html, http://ankit.im/swift/2016/01/07/exploring-swift-array-implementation/, and of course the source code: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb.

Comment: Yes, I need to know from where I can see the source code definition, how item is added in array, and return value when accessed.